# How to Partial render view file in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am working with Laravel 5.4 and every thing working fine. But I am

thinking about the partial view means I don't want to load header and footer

again by again in when any view file show.

Currently  blade file structure like:

```
@extends('site.includes.main')

@section('content')

     <form action = "{{url('school/createSchool'.'#schoolconfirmationform')}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="col-sm-12">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name Here.." class="form-control" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address Here.." class="form-control" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password Here.." class="form-control" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Package</label>
            <input type="text" name="package" value="{{ ucfirst( $packageSession['packageInformation']->name ) }}"  disabled="disabled"  class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Amount</label>
            <input type="text" name="amount" value="{{ $packageSession['packageInformation']->amount  }}"  class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
        </div>


        <button type="submit" style="background-color:#FF8800;border: #FF8800"  class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Submit</button>                 
        </div>
    </form>

@endsection
```

**main.blade.php file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    @include('site.includes.head')
    <body class="page-boxed page-header-fixed page-container-bg-solid page-sidebar-closed-hide-logo ">
        @include('site.includes.header')

        @yield('content')

        @include('site.includes.footer')
    </body>
</html>
```

When I show any blade view file I have to follow above procedure My Question is when I loaded header and footer in a any blade file why I have to include **main.blade.php php** file in every view file.

How to load header and footer once and then view file show in middle. Is It possible in Laravel.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem, you don't have to include header and footer on every page, you just have to extend every page from your `main.blade.php` view.

Comment: You have great example here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-layouts-using-blade

Comment: @Jerodev I am doing same but my question I have to extend every page by main.blade.php I have a lot of content in fotter, I am thing when once time footer loaded ,how to avoid again load footer because every view extend main which has a footer

Comment: @ShahzadDitro You create main *layouts* which you extend in some *content* partial views. You can include as many *partials* as you want in those *layout/content* views. For example you have `blog_layout.blade` which has the full html; then you have `post_content.blade` view which extends the `blog_layout` view; then you can have partials like `post_header.blade`, `post_footer.blade` which do not extend anything but you just use `@include` blade directive to include them inside the *content* view `post_content`.